# Loader component only loaded once

Tags: javascript, qml

When I click the button "add", my QML interface is displayed. If I close this interface, it won't open again. I think my loader is executed only one time.

```
Loader {
    id: idLoader
    onLoaded: {
        console.log("DIALOG LOADED")
    }
}
```

My button:

```
Button {
   id: add
   text: "add"
   width: 100
   onClicked: {
       idLoader.source = "qrc:/folder/MyInterface.qml 
   }
}
```

Comment: How does you close the interface? Btw, you can set `idLoader.source` to empty string. It will automatically close the loaded component, freeing its resources and so you can reload your component with setting the `source` property again.

Comment: MyInterface.qml its a window, when I close this window I cannot to display it again.

Comment: So why you use `Loader` in this case? I think it's just unnecessary here. You can load your component with this code: `var component = Qt.createComponent("MyInterface.qml");
            if (component.status === Component.Ready) 
                component.createObject();`

Comment: Because  I want to pass some parametre (Variable, ID ..)  to my window,

Comment: Ehm ... look up the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method). You can pass all parameters you want to `createObject`, for example:  `component.createObject(parentItem,{x: 100,y: 100});`. Also `createObject` returns reference to object and you can change it after creation

Comment: thank you for your reply it works well. Just that I contact a problem when I click on the button my window appears but it is very heavy to load the data in this window. you know this problem??

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't open again because the `source` doesn't change after the first time. If you want to show your interface a second time, set the `visible` property of `idLoader` to `true`.